# How to use Bloc for beginner in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

I am starting to use Bloc to manage state , I have learned that there are 3 types that are BlocBuilder, BlocListener and BlocConsummer, so which writing style is most commonly used?

I have referenced many sample projects on github, but it has too many ways of writing, so I would like to ask for a sample project to follow it (the one that you feel is best)

Thank you ^^!

Comment: Did you check out https://bloclibrary.dev/#/? Use BlocBuilder if you want to rebuild your widgets depending on your state, use BlocListener if you want to execute a method depending on your state and BlocConsumer is the combination of BlocBuilder & BlocListener

Comment: @quoci I also took a look, but I want a sample project to study

Comment: you can follow this project as a beginner: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-bloc-for-beginners-839e22adb9f5